# How to use Ajax with Wordpress

Tags: ajax, mysql

I am trying to pass a javascript over to a PHP variable by using AJAX. However, I am having a little bit of difficulty understanding Ajax, as I am new to it.

Here is my code:

```
    <form method="post">
    
        <select name="Class_Initial">
        <!-- dropdown data here -->
        </select>

    </form>
    
     <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
               $("#Change1").change(function() {
                   // This toggles the select tag
            var Class_Initial = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
    
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "my_ajax_obj.ajax_url",
                data: Class_Initial = Class_Initial,
                success: function(data) 
                {
                    alert("Success!");
                },
                data: 
                 { 
                     Class_Initial : Class_Initial 
                 }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
            
    <?php
    // How to tie var Class_Initial equal to $A
    $A = $_POST['Class_Initial'];
    ?>
```

As a final note, I want to take the value of var Class_Initial and have it equal to a key in a query.

Ie:

```
$wpdb->query("SELECT X from A Where X = 'Javascript_Value'");
```

Comment: it's probably not an AJAX issue and more basic variable usage, see this: `url: "my_ajax_obj.ajax_url",` instead of saying you want the URL to be the value of `my_ajax_obj.ajax_url` you've told it you want the URL to be literally the name of the variable, not its value: `"my_ajax_obj.ajax_url"`